# Update method doesn't work anymore after upgrading to angular 1.6.0

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I want to update my json object with PUT method using the update function in angularjs but after using the update method I get the error of :

```
angular.js:14324 TypeError: menuFactory.getDishes(...).update is not a function
    at b.$scope.submitComment (controllers.js:104)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15152), <anonymous>:4:159)
    at e (angular.js:26673)
    at b.$eval (angular.js:17958)
    at b.$apply (angular.js:18058)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:26678)
    at bg (angular.js:3613)
    at HTMLFormElement.d (angular.js:3601)
```

This is my service.js code :

```
.service('menuFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function($resource,baseURL) {
            this.getDishes = function(){
                return $resource("localhost:3000/"+"dishes/:id",{update:{method:'PUT' }});

                                };      
    }])
```

and this is my controller code :

```
 .controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', 'menuFactory', function($scope,menuFactory) {

        $scope.mycomment= {rating:"5", comment:"", author:""};

                            $scope.dish.comments.push($scope.mycomment);

            menuFactory.getDishes().update({ id:$scope.dish.id }, $scope.dish);
    }])
```

why angular doesn't recognize the update method , I had the same issues with get method , but after updating my angular to 1.6.0 version the problem with get method solved . but now I have the same problem with Update method.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be calling $resource incorrectly.

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) and look at the usage:

```
$resource(url, [paramDefaults], [actions], options);
```

You were sending in actions as the paramDefault parameters, so just enter an empty literal for that parameter, unless you want to customise it.

Change

```
$resource("localhost:3000/"+"dishes/:id",{update:{method:'PUT' }});
```

to

```
$resource("localhost:3000/"+"dishes/:id",{}, update:{method:'PUT' }});
```

Comment: thanks a lot , worked ! but what does that empty object do?

Comment: Updated answer to reflect that.